# Check if user is still touching screen without touchesMoved()

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm looking for a way to get touchesEnded to get called **before** draw() if the user lifts their finger off the screen before draw() is called. That way the path won't get drawn if touches have ended. I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but thought I'd ask just to make sure.

(This code below is just to demonstrate what I mean, I know it's not good code for a drawing algorithm)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    haveTouchesEnded = false
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    path.addLine(to: touch.location(in:self))
    setNeedsDisplay() //calls draw()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    haveTouchesEnded = true
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if haveTouchesEnded=false{
        path.stroke()
    else{
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I'd like to check somehow if the user is **still** touching the screen in the draw() method. I've tried using a uipangesturerecognizer and checking its state in the draw() method but it doesn't seem to update by the time draw() is called, perhaps because touchesMoved is still being executed so the state is still "changed". I think there might be a complex solution to this that's out of my expertise.

Comment: `touchesEnded` _means_ the finger was lifted. They are the same. Touches. Ended.

Comment: The problem is that draw() is called before touchesEnded is, so as I said I can't use it to check if the user is still touching the screen in draw().

Comment: if touches not ended then his finger is on screen'

Comment: @user3290287 It seems to me that the code you've shown _does_ make that check. Anyway, if `touchesMoved` is where `setNeedsDisplay` is called and that is why `draw` is called, you _know_ the finger _is_ touching the screen, because if it were not, `touchedMoved` would not have been called. The whole question makes no sense.

Comment: Hi matt, it's possible that the user could've let go after touchesMoved was called so I want to check that somehow before a path is drawn (for various complicated reasons). Do you know of any way to check if the user is still touching the screen in an if statement?

Comment: You have mentioned where your approach is failing, but not what exactly you are trying to achieve. There may be other ways of achieving it. e.g. if you just want to avoid drawing very short-timed touches, you can simply log the start time in `touchesBegan` and check a certain amount of  time has passed in `draw` before you actually start drawing the touches, and reset the time in `touchesEnded`. Similarly, if your goal is something else, there might be other solutions.